# Customizing change set uploaded notification

Tags: sandbox, change-set

Is it possible to customize this email alert,

[image]

How this is enabled at first point as I don't see any email alert or any setting to switch on/off this?

And if it is possible to customize, please tell me where can I find this template in my org.

Note: This image is copied from an idea post as I receive the same message when I upload a change in our production org. Just the sandbox names and change set name is updated for our org.

Comment: Nope. The only part of that message you have control over is the name of the change set and email deliverability in the target org.

Comment: @AdrianLarson is it enabled by default?

Comment: Email Deliverability? I think in sandboxes it defaults to `System Only`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @AdrianLarson No not about the Email Deliverability. That we can control. But what about the email that I receive on upload of change set?

Comment: Um, if by that you are asking if you can control the name of the change set by default, then yes.